# How to get frequency of specific character in a list?

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. I have a stored a list of names (first and last) as strings from my text file into a list in python. What I'm trying to figure out how to get the frequency of the second letter in the last name of all the names in the list.

Here's an example of what is in my names list:

```
['Name', 'Allen Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Larry Hackman']
```

From this list the frequency of a should be 1, and the frequency of o should be 2.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 n = open('name.txt', 'r')
    with open('name.txt', 'r') as n:
 nameList  = [line.strip() for line in n]
 print nameList

 from collections import Counter
     nameFreq = Counter(nameList)

 print "The frequency of the second letter in last name is"
 print nameFreq
```

How can I manipulate the counter to counter only the second letter in the last name? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.rsplit` to split the names from the end just once, if length of the returned list is > 1 then use its last item:

`str.rsplit` example:

```
>>> 'foo bar spam'.rsplit(None, 1)
['foo bar', 'spam']
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lis = ['Name', 'Allen Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Larry Hackman']
>>> Counter(y[-1][1] for y in (x.rsplit(None, 1) for x in lis) if len(y)>1)
Counter({'o': 2, 'a': 1})
```

Comment: Ok thanks you so much!!! Also if I wanted to get the first letter of the last name would I use `Counter(y[0][1] for y in nameFreq (x.rsplit(None, 1) for x in nameFreq) if len(y)>1)`.

Comment: @mikez1 Use `y[-1][0]`.

Comment: Ok I set the count to variable c. If I wanted to print the output of the counter can I use a for loop such as `for x in c: print x, c[x]` instead of `Counter({'o': 2, 'a': 1})`

Comment: @mikez1 You can also do: `for k, v in c.iteritems(): print k, v`

Answer (score 0):

Doing two splits it's probably not optimal, but this was the first thing I thought of.

```
>>> Counter([x.split()[1][1] for x in nameList if len(x.split()) > 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.partition` method and the string slicing:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('name.txt') as file:
    names = [line.strip() for line in file]

# 'foo bar spam' -> 'bar spam'
lastnames = (name.partition(' ')[2] for name in names) 
i = 1 # 2nd character
freq = Counter(name[i:i+1] for name in lastnames)
print("\n".join("%s: %d" % (char, n) for char, n in freq.most_common() if char))
```